# Facebook javascript sdk basic login or initialization error

Tags: javascript, facebook, logging, initialization

I have following code mostly copy pasted from https://developers.facebook.com.

```
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <button id="fb-auth">Login</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var button;
        var userInfo;

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({ appId: '864702126886557', // your appId
                status: true,
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: true,
                oauth: true});

           showLoader(true);

           function updateButton(response) {
                button       =   document.getElementById('fb-auth');
                userInfo     =   document.getElementById('user-info');

                if (response.authResponse) {
                    //user is already logged in and connected
                    FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                        login(response, info);
                    });

                    button.onclick = function() {
                        FB.logout(function(response) {
                            logout(response);
                        });
                    };
                } else {
                    //user is not connected to your app or logged out
                    button.innerHTML = 'Login';
                    button.onclick = function() {
                        showLoader(true);
                        FB.login(function(response) {
                            if (response.authResponse) {
                                FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                                    login(response, info);
                                });
                            } else {
                                //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
                                showLoader(false);
                            }
                        }, {scope:'email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,user_about_me'});
                    }
                }
            }

            // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
            FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);
        };

        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";            
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(js);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

When I execute this code I get following error:-

Uncaught Error: invalid version specified sdk.js:96 (anonymous function)

Line from sdk.js:96 :-

__d("sdk.ErrorHandling",["ManagedError","sdk.Runtime","sdk.Scribe","sdk.UA","sdk.feature","wrapFunction"],function(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l){b.__markCompiled&&b.__markCompiled();var m=k('error_handling',false),n='';function o(u){var v=u._originalError;delete u._originalError;i.log('jssdk_error',{appId:h.getClientID(),error:u.name||u.message,extra:u});throw v;}function p(u){var v={line:u.lineNumber||u.line,message:u.message,name:u.name,script:u.fileName||u.sourceURL||u.script,stack:u.stackTrace||u.stack};v._originalError=u;if(j.chrome()&&/([\w:./]+.js):(\d+)/.test(u.stack)){v.script=RegExp.$1;v.line=parseInt(RegExp.$2,10);}for(var w in v)(v[w]==null&&delete v[w]);return v;}function q(u,v){return function(){if(!m)return u.apply(this,arguments);try{n=v;return u.apply(this,arguments);}catch(w){if(w instanceof g)throw w;var x=p(w);x.entry=v;var y=ES(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),'map',true,function(z){var aa=Object.prototype.toString.call(z);return (/^[object (String|Number|Boolean|Object|Date)]$/).test(aa)?z:z.toString();});x.args=ES('JSON','stringify',false,y).substring(0,200);o(x);}finally{n='';}};}function r(u){if(!u.__wrapper)u.__wrapper=function(){try{return u.apply(this,arguments);}catch(v){window.setTimeout(function(){throw v;},0);return false;}};return u.__wrapper;}function s(u,v){return function(w,x){var y=v+':'+(n||'[global]')+':'+(w.name||'[anonymous]'+(arguments.callee.caller.name?'('+arguments.callee.caller.name+')':''));return u(l(w,'entry',y),x);};}if(m){setTimeout=s(setTimeout,'setTimeout');setInterval=s(setInterval,'setInterval');l.setWrapper(q,'entry');}var t={guard:q,unguard:r};e.exports=t;},null);

Then I tried to changed code from

```
  js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
```

to

```
 js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.1";
```

or

```
 js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
```

which brings additional warnings

Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id.

FB.init has already been called - this could indicate a problem

and same previous error:

Uncaught Error: invalid version specified at sdk.js:96

What is wrong with this code and how to just simply initialize or log in to facebook. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to specify the version in the init function?

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'your-app-id',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.1'
        });
      };
```

Comment: After this change I get this message: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more ping?client_id=797565713614652&domain=&origin=1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2F…:1

given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains. Not that I have Valid OAuth redirect URIs configured in dev.facebook as http://localhost:9000/_oauth-callback/. I don't know where this redirect_uri came.

Comment: I was following this tutorial http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/new-javascript-sdk-oauth-2-0-based-fbconnect-tutorial/. But there is nothing like this. It must be pointing to my own app id. Should have anything from tutorial

Comment: Facebook checks, if the redirect domain is registered for the given appId for security reasons.  You can configure the allowed domains here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/